# How to add white space between two divs of 6 columns each in foundation 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, zurb-foundation

I am developing a website in Zurb Foundation 4 and SASS.

My code looks like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 columns redbg"> content goes here... </div>
   <div class="large-6 columns greenbg"></div>
</div>
```

Both of inner divs has background. I have a column gutter of 30px.I want this gutter to be white. The possible solution for it to add parent divs for both of inner divs and apply columns and large-6 class to it and this way code will look like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="redbg">  content goes here... </div>
   </div>
   <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="greenbg"> content goes here... </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But by applying this solution I have to create two divs for only the sake of design. Can anyone please guide how to do it or a better approach.

Also I wonder how to collapse a column from just one side (left or right)?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use CSS - by using the [`background-clip`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip) property, which as its name suggests, allows you to clip the painting area of an elements background.

Since the gutter width in foundation is within the padding box, you can use the `content-box` value.

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/CA669/950/embedded/result/

Comment: This is actually really cool, I didn't know about how to use background-clip.  In the jsFiddle the red one has `!important` and the green one doesn't.  When I view it the red one is the only one that it affects.  Do you really have to use !important for this to work?  Just curious.

Comment: I like it but does this supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Yes, it is [supported](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) by all major browsers - with the exception of IE8. @Fernker: Nope that was not intentional. This property works whether you use `!important` or not.

Comment: The green div though is going out to the edge of its padding but the red one isn't.  But if I put `!important` on the green background-clip then it seems to work properly.   (Chrome Dev, Mac)

EDIT:  I changed the order of the properties on the green div and that makes it work.  Really strange.

Answer (score -1):

Can you make the row have a white background?  That way the gutter will be white.

The other way I can think of is how you are currently doing it.  I've had to do similar solutions.

Comment: With which of my code? first one or second one. It works with second one but in that case my question is still there. Don't you think two more divs are unnecessary nodes to DOM? with first code this is not happening.

Comment: Oh sorry, with the first example, so you'd have a .row with a .whitebg and then the two children columns that have their respective colors. 

Yes two more divs are a bit more unnecessary but I don't think it's a huge issue.  It's part of the trade-off of using a framework but it really isn't the end of the world to use two extra divs.