# How to add a margin in Foundation5 grid between two columns without using offset?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 but I met a somewhat weird problem. Because I want to use different background-colors and borders for two columns and I need space in between them.
I included the jsfiddle at the bottom, but first the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-9 columns content">
        The custom CSS is at the bottom of the CSS window.
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns sidebar">
        Edit it to see that the paddings change!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divider"><p>Space</p></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 offset-1 columns content">
        The custom CSS is at the bottom of the CSS window.
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns sidebar">
        Edit it to see that the paddings change!
    </div>
</div>
```

In the second row, I used the "offset" function, but it gives me too much space between the columns. All I need is some standard 10 to 20 px.

Does anyone have a clue how to manage this with foundation5? I want to have a static margin between those two columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/pXVR3/19/

With high regards,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this thread:
[How to add white space between two divs of 6 columns each in foundation 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842240/how-to-add-white-space-between-two-divs-of-6-columns-each-in-foundation-4?rq=1)

You just use an extra div within the div that contains the grid information like this:

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns"><div class="content"></div></div>
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns"><div class="sidebar"></div></div>
  </div>
```

And now you just apply the background-color to the grid div and the padding to the inner divs.

Thanks.